# Does windows media creation tool on USB delete personal files on the computer where it runs?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb, bsod, media-creation-tool

I have an old computer with win7 on it. For whatever reasons, I suddenly cannot access the operating system, even in safe mode(BSOD all the time). Now I plan to install win10 on it with a USB created by media creation tool so that I can access an operating system.

**Question:** **If I choose to install win10 on C:/, will the files in D:/ or any other partition be affected or deleted?** I cannot access the OS so I cannot backup the files in the PC anymore until I have a new OS.

Comment: Back up any data you cannot afford to lose on an external drive, then disconnect it before installing W10.

Comment: If you upgrade to w10 while booted in W7 it will keep all personal files, but back up to protect those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the USB install process you will be asked where on your HDD you wish to install Windows 10. Highlighted is exactly what NOT to do.

[image: Windows 10 setup choice screen]

Pick the partition that has your original Windows 7 installation on. Assuming that there is enough space this will rename the windows 7 install to Windows.old and install Windows 10 in a new Windows folder.

You may need to install windows 10 on another partition/disk if there isn't enough space - I think the minimum space it needs is 30gb - but you will need an extra 50gb minimum due to the updates etc.

The only place you can accidently delete your stuff is in that screen above.